# Валидация в nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, валидация

Подскажите как сделать валидацию и какие библиотеки используете ?

К примеру у меня есть модель категория у нее 2 поля `name` и `url`. `name` и `url` не могут быть пустыми и `url` уникальное поле.

У меня есть контроллер который достает нужные поля из запроса и передает их в сервис `categoryService`, я сделал таким образом, может есть какой то лучше способ:

```
  async createCategory (data) {
    const errors = saveCategoryValidation(data)

    if (Object.keys(errors).length) {
      const error = new Error('invalid category data')

      error.errors = errors

      throw error
    }

    const category = await knex('categories').insert(data)

    return category
  },
```

saveCategoryValidation:

```
export default async (data) => {
  const messages = {}

  if (_.isNil(data.name) || !data.name.length) {
    messages.name = 'Name is required'
  }

  if (_.isNil(data.url) || !data.url.length) {
    messages.name = 'Name is required'
  } else {
    const categories = await knex('categories')
      .select('id')
      .where('url', data.url)

    if (categories.length) {
      messages.url = 'Url already in use'
    }
  }

  return messages
}
```

Comment: Может быть лучше валидацию прикрутить как-то в контроллер?

Comment: "url уникальное поле."  я бы просто вшил в схему базы и при ошибке добавления предлагал подкорректировать, проверка на пустые поля хех: if(data.name)